# Page with background video occasionally gets zoomed out

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

Our web app has a login page that uses video.js and bigvideo.js to render a background video. Occasionally the page will get zoomed way out (see attached image) and the accompanying error message will show in the console log:

Failed to load resource 
Video Error -> *V*.Event

We are using video.js version 3.2 and bigvideo.js version 1.0.0-2.

So far we have only detected this issue with chrome on windows 7.

The video is an mp4 file.

[image: screenshot]